# Cannot get image on localhost

Tags: node.js, image, twitter-bootstrap, express

I am working on a Node.js Express project and have used Bootstrap carousal template in index.ejs page. The image tag is not working if I try to get the image saved inside the project under "views" folder.

```
 <img  class="img-circle" src= "/proj1.png"  />
```

The index.ejs file is also in "views" folder. The error is: GET http://localhost:3000/proj1.png 404 (Not Found).
I have tried changing the relative path of the file also but it did not work.

Comment: Your path doesn't seem correct

Comment: Your `views` folder is probably set up to only serve `.ejs` files to the view engine. You need to create a separate `public` folder and in there `images`, `scripts`, `styles` folders for serving images, Javascript, and CSS files respectively and then serve them using [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html). Please see the default Express app directory [here](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html). I suggest using the generator if you are beginning to use Express. It's easier to learn Express that way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

YOu have to serve your static files from express:

try Adding this:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

(`public` is the folder where your images and everything (assets) reside)

More infos here: http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell express from where should it serve static content.

`app.use(express.static('/path/to/your/folder'))`.

Source: http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

In production, it's a general convention to serve static files using nginx.
Look it up.